# How adding two buttons at the end of listview in the second activity?

Tags: android

I have list of items, when click on the item, direct to next activity with this item same selected.So, add on. I would like putting in  the second activity two buttons at the end of the items selected.What ways I can do it?
In the method create() next activity:

```
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, produtos, R.layout.pedidos_list, de, para);

    adapter.setViewBinder(this);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    Button btAdicionar =    new Button(this);
    btAdicionar.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f));


    btAdicionar.setText("Adicionar");
    btAdicionar.setId(R.id.button_adicionar_pedidos_list);
    btAdicionar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            adicionarProduto(v);
        } });

    getListView().addFooterView(btAdicionar);

    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Your question is tough to understand. Do you want to add two buttons after you are taken to the second activity? If so, you want to add them to the end of a listview?

Comment: Stay at the end of the layout, next activity

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add the two buttons at the end of the xml view. You probably have a Scrollview with the listView inside, so align two buttons under that and you'll be able to scroll it down.

Is that what you want?

Please, put the xml code from where you want to add the button or something like thi, its very helpful to know where exactly you want that.

Comment: I need add two buttons dinamically after list items selected in other activity. because I click an item repeat two buttons